# Centering inline-block DIV with CSS ":before" ruins text centering both vertical and horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, centering

Hello everyone I have this set up to center some div based buttons but I'm having some visual glitches when centering text (it is not really centered):

```css
#slide2
{
 text-align: center;
 text-align-last: center; 
 -moz-text-align-last: center;
}

#container2
{
height:100%;
}

.pagesContainer
{

        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        top:0%;
 }


.pageButtonContent
{
 width: 38px;
 height: 38px;
 background-color:white;
 border: solid 1px black;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
     font-size: 20px;
     color:darkgray;
     border-radius: 50%;
     

}

.pageButtonContent:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height:42px;
}


.pagesContainer:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='Slide' id='slide2' onscroll='changePosition()'>
 <div id = "container2" class="containert">

 <div id='' class='pagesContainer'>
  
   <div id='previous' class='pageButtonContent'>
      1
   </div>
  
  
  
   <div id='' class='pageButtonContent'>
   2
   </div>
  
 
 
   <div id='' class='pageButtonContent'>
   3
   </div>
  
  
   
   <div id='next' class='pageButtonContent'>
      4
   </div>
  

 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I know there are many different ways of doing it, but so far this set up is the only one that has worked, and I don't want to go back and try to explain all to stay in subject.

For some reason after applying css `:before` centered text appears to be kinda off. It looks like I manage to fix it vertically by setting a 42px height (its container is 50px high), but I haven't figure out how to fix it horizontally, do you guys and gals have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't really need :before to make it work. 
You can add line-height to center the numbers vertically:

```
.pageButtonContent { line-height: 38px;}
```

Comment: I'm really tempted to mark it as an answer but it is not 100% perfect it is still off by a pixel. Lets wait to see if someone can figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should try with different values until you make it work well for you. Using line-height instead of :before for regulating text vertically is the logical thisng to do.

Comment: You were right, the problem is actually the font smoothing. If you look at the picture you will notice it. Without inline-block it renders differently.  Thank you. http://imgur.com/fgvrrSa